# I want to read the xml response displayed in the eclipse console to assert with the expected xml.

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, console

I want to read the xml responce displayed in the eclipse console to assert with the expected xml. Can somebody please help me to read the output from the console of eclipse while running my test....

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you need to do? What is the XML you want to display, and what is the assertion that you want to make? What kind of test are you running, is it JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are trying to assert two XML's using Junit etc? Also I am not sure of what you mean by reading from Console?

If you are writing the code to assert using two XML's using Junit & XMLUnit Below link can help.

[XML's Comparison](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/xml-comparison-tutorial-using-xmlunit)

[XML unit's Example Code](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/example.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse console simply displays what's printed to the standard output. If you aren't concerned about spurious output, then you can quite simply print whatever information might be useful to standard output, and it should end up there, assuming that you have the debugger properly attached to the running process.

I can't think of a ready way to do it automatically when an assertion fails, though, since it will most likely be local in scope (so you can't catch and rethrow the generated exception).

Simple calls to `System.out.println()` should give you a start.